# Cucumber JVM HTML [masterthought] report customization

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using [damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen) in my automation for report generation.

I would like to make a few customizations to my project.

1. I want to modify the column headers of the summary table. Specifically, I would like to change 'Feature' to 'Scenario', 'Scenarios' to 'Scenario Status', and 'Features' to 'Duration'.
2. There are six tabs present in the top right corner of the screen such as Jenkins, Latest Results, Features, Tags, etc. However, I only require the 'Features' tab i.e. the summary screen.
3. In the graph, want only Scenario and Steps

Refer screenshot.

Please note I am not using TestNG or BDD framework.

I am using the below code for report generation

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Reportable;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.json.support.Status;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.presentation.PresentationMode;

public class CucumberReportGeneration {

  public static void generateCucumberReport() {

    File reportOutputDirectory = new File("./target/cucumber-reports");
    List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Read all JSON files from the "json_folder" directory
    File jsonFolder = new File("./target/cucumber-reports/json_files");
    File[] fileList = jsonFolder.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".json"));
    
    for (File file : fileList) {
        jsonFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    
    String buildNumber = "1";
    String projectName = "Project";
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
    
    // optional configuration - check javadoc for details
    configuration.addPresentationModes(PresentationMode.RUN_WITH_JENKINS);
    
    // do not make scenario failed when step has status SKIPPED
    configuration.setNotFailingStatuses(Collections.singleton(Status.SKIPPED));
    configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);
    
    // additional metadata presented on main page
    configuration.addClassifications("Platform", "Windows");
    configuration.addClassifications("Browser", "Firefox");
    configuration.addClassifications("Branch", "release/1.0");
    configuration.addClassifications("Executed on Machine", "DUMMY");// optionally add metadata presented on main page via properties file
    List<String> classificationFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    configuration.addClassificationFiles(classificationFiles); // optionally specify qualifiers for each of the report json files
    configuration.addPresentationModes(PresentationMode.PARALLEL_TESTING);
    configuration.setQualifier("cucumber-report-1", "First report");
    
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);

    Reportable result = reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
}
```

[image: Sample Cucumber Report]